# PyQt5 QDialog is modal but blocks MainWindow

Tags: python, pyqt5

i have a Filter Dialog, wich is used to set the query for the filter, but i have 2 problems with this.

First of all, i want to open a dialog without blocking the interactions in the MainWindow.
And second if i use .show() on the dialog, it just opens for a mili second, and the closes itself instant.

Here is the code for my Dialog:

```
class FilterDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, main_window=None) -> None:
        super(FilterDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Suchen & Filtern")
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowType.Window)
```

And this is my MainWindow:

```
class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(App, self).__init__()

    def open_filter_dialog(self) -> None:
        filter_dialog = FilterDialog(self)
        filter_dialog.exec()
```

The code for the Dialog and the MainWindow are in the same File.

Comment: The code has some indentation issues. Also, please make a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The current code contains tons of stuff that is completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I accidentally added the above comment as an answer.

Comment: If you don't know which parts of the code are relevant to the issue, making a MRE is very helpfull, and can often lead to finding the answer yourself. There are two approaches: either start extremely minimal and add code until the problem is reproduced, or start with the full code and strip away from it until the issue is no longer reproduced (and then add the last thing back).

Comment: I can reproduce the issue when changing `filter_dialog.exec()` to `filter_dialog.show()`. The immediate closing is because you don't keep a persistent reference to the dialog and it is garbage collected as soon as the function returns. To solve, either pass the `main_window` argument on to the `super()` call in the constructor of `FilterDialog`. That way the dialog has a parent and won't be destriyed. Or make `filter_dialog` an instance variable like in @Nova's answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked, i just had to pass the main window as parent to the dialog, and it works.

Comment: If you keep the dialog alive by setting a parent, you should also add the line `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` to the `FilterDialog.__init__`. Without this, the code will have a memory leak, because a new dialog will be created *every time* `open_filter_dialog` is called and Qt won't automatically delete it (because it still has a parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, when using the .show it automatically closes within few milliseconds! But when I try it on my own, it doesn't! You can try the code I've written below and take it as an example since it's working fine for me.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class FilterDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, main_window=None) -> None:
        super(FilterDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Suchen & Filtern")
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')

        self.filter_button = QPushButton('Open Filter Dialog', self)
        self.filter_button.setGeometry(150, 150, 150, 50)
        self.filter_button.clicked.connect(self.open_filter_dialog)

    def open_filter_dialog(self) -> None:
        self.filter_dialog = FilterDialog(self)
        self.filter_dialog.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If it still closes, try surrounding your app with a Try & Except, I think the main cause of the closing is an error not the .show()